# PHP exec tracert progressive display

Tags: php, windows, exec, progressive

Trying to display my results progressively, as it would be displayed in CMD.
(ie: line by line)

Not even sure where to start?

```
    <?php
$ip = "8.8.8.8";

exec("tracert -d ".$ip." && exit", $output);

    foreach($output as $out){
    echo $out;
    echo '<br>';
    }

?>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: if you are very luck [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) after each echo may work, but there's a lot of factors at pay here. have you considered a js approach?

Comment: `exec` will return when the command finishes. If you need to display at "real time", consider `<pre>` and `system()` or `passthru()`.

Comment: use `ob_end_flush()` and `ob_flush()` with `str_pad()`